# Medical history and working in UAE

Tags: medical, uae, qualifications

I was researching working in the UAE, and the official site indicates the main requirement is not to be carrying a communicable disease upon entry (women have to in addition test negative for pregnancy).

Looking deeper though, it appears that there might be a stigma at the employer level against those who have had diseases like cancer, or undergone heart surgery, or are managing lupus. For sure, there are situations where people lost their jobs if diagnosed, but I couldn't find much for those who were diagnosed, treated, and made a full recovery prior to getting in.

Just wondering if any expats have experience with this, and how big a factor it is?